# Save substring from field to copyfield using regex in Solr

Tags: regex, solr

I'm importing data from mysql table using import handler. I have a column `msg`, of type `text`. Using regex, I have to save substring in a copy field.

```
msg: 94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding pnr:986|0978325
```

Expected Solr result:

```
{
    "msg_body": "94eb2c0cb17ef354bb052c57f40c\\r\\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\\r\\nContent-Transfer-Encoding pnr:986-0978325",
    "pnr_number": "pnr:986-0978325"

}
```

My REGEX:

```
(pnr|(P|p)[ _.:,!"'-/$](N|n)[ _.:,!"'-/$](R|r))+[ _.:,!"'-/$]+[0-9]{3}[ _.:,!"'-/$]+[0-9]{7}
```

Please help me out as i'm new to solr

Comment: I seems you are new to regex too. There are several problems with your regex. Try testing it on one of the many online regex testers.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define a custom field for pnr_number. 
Use a copyField to copy msg_body to pnr_number
In the custom field definition, use

```
<filter class="solr.PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory" pattern="regex goes here" preserve_original="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Data Import Handler, you have 3 options:

1. Use a [Regex Transformer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-TheRegexTransformer) in DIH definition.
2. Use a [RegexReplaceProcessorFactory Update Request Processor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors) (in solrconfig.xml).
3. Use a Regex filter in the analyzer chain

With the first two options, the regex will extract the pattern before the field is actually indexed. In the last option, the stored representation (if you store the field) will contain the original full string, but the indexed (searchable) representation will contain regex match.